# VueJS: Show content of PromiseResult that is returned from computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, computed-properties

I have computed property as shown below which returns `res`, where `res` is a Promise object. The reason I am not able to have this script inside `created()` or `mounted()` hook is because `this.selectedObject` is `null` when I do so.

I am happy with `res`, however, the problem comes when I need to render `PromiseResult` in html:  `<div>{{ currentDepStatus }}</div>`. This shows `[Promise object]` instead of showing content of PromiseResult. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
  computed: {
    currentDepStatus() {
      let res = '';
      if (!this.selectedObject) return [];
      const deps = this.depCategory(this.selectedObject.id);
      if (deps.length > 0) {
        res = sendDepStatus(deps);
      }
      return res;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an anti-pattern for how you want to do this. `computed` properties need to simple `getters` for nested reactive values. Any external operation should be inside `methods`

After seeing your problem, here is how I will do it.

```
data() {
  currentDepStatus: []
}
watch: {
 async selectedObject() {
   if (this.selectedObject) {
      const deps = this.depCategory(this.selectedObject.id);
      if (deps.length > 0) {
        this.currentDepStatus = await sendDepStatus(deps);
      }
    }
  }
}

<div>{{ currentDepStatus }}</div>
```